# Connect to Mongo DB on a remote server behind LDAP using perl

Tags: perl, mongodb, ldap, tunneling

So I intend to connect to mongoDB which is on a remote server behind LDAP.
The mongoDB by itself has no username/password setup, but the server on which mongoDB is running is behind LDAP.

My question is how do I setup the server tunneling username/password configuration to connect to MongoDB

I am using the mongoDB module from cpan.

lets assume -

LDAP credentials are

username - ldapuser

password - ldappassword

I do know how to setup if the mongoDB has a username and password

```
my $connection = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'mongodb://perlnewbi3.remoteserver.com:27107', username => 'dbuser', password => 'dbpass', db_name => 'testdb');
my $database = $connection->testdb;
```

As always any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I also get an error which is somehow related "can't get db response, not connected at xxxxxxxxx/xxx/x/lib/MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 260"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole thing is really a question of permissions rather than a question of how to use MongoDB.

There are two basic methods:

1. Ensure that the Perl app in running in the correct user context so that it can see port 27017 on `remoteserver.com`.
2. Create a secured tunnel on the local machine, typically with something like SSH. Then update your connection in PERL to point to the correct port on the local machine. (`mongodb://localhost:27017`)

Option #1 is probably the ideal solution, however, Option #2 is probably simplest option to setup.

Comment: I intend to run these scripts off Jenkins/Hudson, which are running as a Jenkins user on the Jenkins machine, so option 1 basically gets eliminated for me. As the jenkins user is not setup on LDAP. I can only access the MongoDB server using my personal credentials to go pass LDAP. Your second option seems somehow possible, but could you please elaborate in detail how I can achieve it.